# Problems with Azure Authentication Redirect in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application that is using an Azure AD Application for oauth authentication. I have followed the Microsoft tutorial here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

Everything works great for me, as long as I'm using my SpringBoot API directly. It also works great for my Angular 7 application, until the token is no longer valid.

Once my token is invalid because it timed out, or I restart the SB application, I can still make API calls and re-authenticate with Azure, but any calls that are made by the Angular application are met wor

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=c6123459-dca3-4999-b368-acdbad8b113e&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state=Fx4vaiGrTwkyXMB5aeKJCE1DAJIeezy8doHiOhvdmrM%3D&redirect_uri=https://somedomain.com/login/oauth2/code/azure' (redirected from 'https://somedomain.com/aa/resources/v1.0/customers?searchString=companyX') from origin 'https://somedomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried adding headers to my Angular Calls, to all SpringBoot calls, but this appears to be something inside of the Azure Application is unhappy with. I have not seen any configuration in Azure that I can make.

any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems you have configured interactive authentication with AAD instead of JWT Bearer token authentication as is typically done for APIs. I don't really have a sample to link to, but essentially your API needs to accept JWTs, and your Angular app needs to handle authentication with MSAL.js.

Comment: I'm new to mod_auth, would it be easier to configure Bearer token authentication?

Comment: In looking at my Azure Configuration, I have implicit grant flow enabled for Access Tokens & ID Tokens.

Comment: @juunas I'm still struggling with this. Do you have any other info you could add?